# Html generated JavaScript not working with other JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a html that is generated by a JavaScript. I also have another separate JavaScript that suppose to hide and do other things to that html. The problem is that html is not responding to any of the other javascript's functions or methods.

I tried including Javascript within that Javascipt but that doesn't seem to work

**HTML**

```
<head>
     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/java1.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "js/java2.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body id = "example">

</body>
```

**Javascript1**

```
function creatething(){
    var html ='';

    html += '<div id = "button">Button <div id = "hide"> EXAMPLE </div> </div>'

    return html;

}

function insertHTML(id, html) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    if(!el) {
        alert('Element with id ' + id + ' not found.');
    }

    el.innerHTML = html;
}

function run() {
    var html = creatething();

    insertHTML('example', html);
}

window.onload = run;
```

**Javascript2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#hide').hide();
});
```

Comment: I know I was lazy to type out the whole word javascript =x

Comment: `java2.js` appears to depend on a library, such a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The HTML will need to include this dependency as well.

Comment: Also, `window.onload` probably runs after the  `$(document).ready(...)` callback.

Comment: When you invoke `hide()` does the element *actually exist* at that time?  "JavaScript 1" seems like a really round-about way to add static markup to the page.  Seems like you can just... add the markup to the page instead.

Comment: @David - I suspect this is a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than a real-world case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problen you have is order of events.

```
window.onload = run;  <-- Creates button
$(document).ready(function() {  <-- hides button
```

Document Ready fires before onload. You add the element onload and hide it onready.

It is like eating a pizza before you make it.

Comment: So do I have to switch the order of when the java script is being called in the head?

Comment: Switching order? You need to make sure that you call the hide code after the element is added. How you do it is up to you.

Comment: switching as in calling java2 first then calling java1

Comment: Make the pizza before you eat it. So the ready code needs to fire onload....And it needs to be registered after the first onload. Or move the other to onready. OR even better, set the hidden state in the CSS to start and do not run the JavaScript!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of adding JavaScript to either the file or away to inject it before the tab loads (e.g. browser add-on) then you can do use

```
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(document.readyState === 'interactive') {
      alert('interactive');
    }
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
      alert('complete');
    }
  }
```

from the MDN, "Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete" once it has loaded."